# Resize Image binary

Tags: c, binary, hex, image-resizing

Now, I'm having a very difficult problem
I convert a font to hex code, and can resize it
as follows :
1. I use lcd font maker software to create char A font Arial size 18
2. Then I convert to hex code
(see picture to understand)

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]

How do I resize the image when data input is hex code or binary, and result is hex code or binary?
Please suggest me, or document related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here i dont know what do you mean by  **resize the image**

1>  In lcd font maker software you have created one image

2>  Now you have encoded that image in digital form and made array of hex code.

Now i think you want to pass this array of hex code to some other program and want to recreate/decode that image back ? if then you can write one program using same reverse logic which can decode that data and create original image back.

And if you want to resize image then you need to understand/use the concept of pixcel sampleling and all stuff

Answer (score 0):

[Wiki page "Image scaling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) could be good stating point. There is list of different scaling methods.

Result of scaling may look ugly, especially if you have 2 color display. 
So consider use of two or more presized fonts.